# pyephem advances observer date on NeverUpError

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, pyephem

**First Question:**
I'm looping over a large group of lat/lons and dates to find moon rise/set times.  Some of these points are near the poles.
The following code advances the observer's date on `NeverUpError`

```
moon = ephem.Moon()
obs = ephem.Observer()
obs.lat='89'
obs.lon='0'
obs.date = ephem.Date('2014/01/01')
print obs.date
# 2014/1/1 00:00:00
obs.next_rising(moon)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   ...
# ephem.NeverUpError: 'Moon' transits below the horizon at 2014/1/1 12:04:01
print obs.date
# 2014/1/1 12:04:01
```

Is there a way to check for this before calling `obs.next_rising(moon)`?  I would like to retain the date in the observation.  I currently use a try/except block to catch it and reset the date.  Is there a better way?

**Second Question:**
Related to the first, is the library thread safe? I set it up to calculate multiple dates at a time in separate threads using the Queue and threading modules.

Answer (score 1):

**First answer:** the fact that the date changes is a bug in PyEphem that should be fixed when the next version is released! For now, setting the date back manually seems to be the simplest workaround.

**Second answer:** As long as each thread has its own `Moon` and `Observer` objects, it should be able to do its own computations without ruining those of any other threads.